# Can chrome extension control devtools and simulating devices?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I know how to simulate a mobile device in devtools, but can I make it easier as a button in a chrome extension? I want to have a chrome extension that quickly changes the device used, add the device frame, and take a picture.

Comment: Extensions can use `chrome.debugger` API to send the same [Emulation](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Emulation/) command directly. You can use devtools `Protocol monitor` to find the exact parameters it uses itself.

Comment: I don't have time to try it now, but that seems like the push I needed. Thank you

Comment: @JasonHocker Did you make any progress on this?

Answer (score 0):

Extensions can use [the `chrome.debugger` API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/debugger/) to communicate with tabs through the [Chrome DevTools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/).

First you need [attach a debugger to a tab](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/debugger/#method-attach). Once attached, you can [send commands](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/debugger/#method-sendCommand) to the attached tab.

```js
chrome.debugger.attach({ tabId: tab.id }, "1.3", () => {
  try {
    const cookies = chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId: tab.id }, "Network.getCookies");
    console.log(cookies);
  } catch(e){
    console.log('e', e);
  }
});
```

The list of commands can be found on [the Chrome DevTools Protocol page](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/).

You’ll most likely also will need to do some orchestration about which tabs are attached and which ones are not. You can find some inspiration in [this extension example](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/blob/5bf419b385860a334a6c2f5c7f0de5ec9a6dcc7b/_archive/mv2/api/debugger/pause-resume/background.js).